# REGEX pattern to increment a counter on replacements

Tags: ruby, regex, perl, sed

In a replacement pattern, is there any way to print the NUMBER of the replacement as in a counter?

I have a series of code blocks I need to process in an HTML file, but in each replaced block I need to increment the counter by 1.

So

```
<p class-"foo">Some text</p>
<p class-"foo">Other text</p>
```

needs to be

```
<p id="1">Some text</p>
<p id="2">Other text</p>
```

I have many lines, I would love to avoid manually entering those numbers.  How can i do this, the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl:

```
my $html = <<END;
<p class="foo">Some text</p>
<p class="foo">Other text</p> 
END

my $n = 0;
$html =~ s/<p class="toc0">/'<p class="foo" id="'.++$n.'">'/eg;

print $html;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<p id="1">Some text</p>
<p id="2">Other text</p>
```

---

For a command-line version to read from a file

```
perl -pe 's/<p class="toc0">/q(<p class="foo" id=").++$n.q(">)/eg' myfile.html
```

Comment: This looks like it would do wht I want, but I oversimplified my code for the purposes of making it easier to understand.

I am actually looking to replace with a couple of backreferences:

    `<p class="toc0"><a href="part0004.xhtml#c01">TOOLS AND MATERIALS</a></p>`

Where I need to capture and re-use the href and the link text.  I tried this but must be missing something:

    `$html =~ s/<p class="toc0"><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>/'<p class="foo" id="'.++$n.'"><a href="'.$1.'">'.$2.'</a>/eg;`

Comment: I found it, was misplaced punctuation.  Thanks.

How could this script be modified to take a text files as input instead of putting the text in it as above?

Comment: @Steve: I've added a command-line version to my answer. From what you have said I don't think there's a reason to capture and put back the parts you want to keep - just edit the opening `<p class="toc0">` and leave the rest untouched.

Comment: perl's `q(...)` operator is for literal strings, for example `q(\n)` gives `\n` not newline. for interpolation use `qq(...)` ([docs](https://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl))

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
perl -pe 's/<p class-"foo">/"<p id=\"" . (++$count) . "\">"/eg'
```

using the `/e` flag to treat the replacement as an expression rather than a string.

Comment: Your BEGIN block is redundant. The `++` operator will increment an undefined variable to 1.

Answer (score 1):

use awk

```
{ cat -<<EOS
  <p class-"foo">Some text</p>
  <p class-"foo">Other text</p> 
EOS
} | awk '/<p class/{sub(/class-".*"/, "id=\""++i "\"");print}'
```

**output**

```
<p id-1>Some text</p>
<p id-2>Other text</p>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pwe 's/<p\s+\Kclass-"foo">/ $i++; qq(id="$i">) /e' yourfile
```

The `\K` is used to keep whatever comes before it, which is convenient in this case. Using a replacement that is evaluated and contains several (two) statements is also convenient, to avoid concatenating and complicating quoting. It is only the return value of the entire statement that is inserted, i.e. the last statement.

When you've tried it out and want to alter the files, you can simply add the `-i` option. I would recommend using backups, like so:

```
perl -i.bak -pwe '....etc'
```

(Backup in `filename.ext.bak`)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
irb(main):001:0> s = %Q{<p class-"foo">Some text</p>\n<p class-"foo">Other text</p>}
irb(main):002:0> id=0; s.gsub(/class-"foo"/) { id+=1; %Q[id="#{id}"] }
=> "<p id=\"1\">Some text</p>\n<p id=\"2\">Other text</p>"
```